# Using getline() to read lines from stdin repeatedly and storing them in an array of strings

Tags: c, getline

I'm trying to use the function `getline()` that is embeded in another function that checks some siple conditions:

```c
int scanItem( char ** list, size_t size ){
    int res = getline( list, &size, stdin );
    if ( res > 5 && res < 100 ){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to store every new line that is coming from the stdin stream into a new strings that is in an array of strings. There seems to be a problem though, every time I load the input, the one that was loaded before it is replaced with the new one.

```c
int main(void){
    char ** inputList = (char**)malloc( sizeof(char) * 100 * 100 );
    size_t size = 100*100;

    int i = 0;
    while ( scanItem(&inputList[i], size) == 1 ){
        i++;
    }
    if ( ! feof(stdin) ){
        error();
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Not sure if I'm using the function correctly...

Comment: You're storing the same pointer in every slot of your array. You could use something like `strdup` to make a copy each time and store that pointer. You will need to `free` each of the strings individually when you're done with them to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: You want a new allocation for each call of `getline`, so you should be doing `char *s = NULL; getline(&s, ...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for `getline` to allocate new pointer for each call, the pointer passed to it needs to point to a NULL.  You have

```
char ** inputList = (char**)malloc( sizeof(char) * 100 * 100 );
```

which allocates space for 10000/sizeof(char *) pointers, but doesn't initialize them to anything, so you end up with undefined behavior when `getline` reads these uninitialized pointers.  Instead you want something like

```
char ** inputList = calloc(100, sizeof(char *));
```

to allocate spaces for 100 pointers, and initialize them all to 0.  Then for your loop, you want something like:

```
int i = 0;
while ( i < 100 && scanItem(&inputList[i], 0) == 1 ){
    i++;
}
```

This ensures you don't run off the end of your list.  The `size` value is not really important as `getline` will ignore the input value if the pointer is NULL and `scanItem` will throw away the returned value.